# Customizing a web application before auto-deploying it

Tags: tomcat, cloud, war, web-deployment

### The application scenario

I have a bunch of Tomcat servers on an IaaS cloud service, so they are all under my control.

These servers will (the application is in design stage) run any Java application container software, such as Tomcat, JBoss, Websphere.

Apart from what solution is the best, I have a web application (a WAR) of which I have full source code. Like in any decent hosting environment, set up of a new user implies deploying a fresh new copy of the same web application to a different application context (say, copy the WAR as `newuser.war` and let Tomcat eat it).

The application is completely based on Spring and Hibernate. It's powered by Maven.

Since we run on IaaS, we are *considering* adding a requirement to our management software. If an application server goes down, redeploying the webapps it runs on a different node, and/or automatically request cloud provider provisioning of a new machine (especially when registered users increase). We **don't currently have** a PaaS service at our provider. Discussing cloud providers supporting Java Webapps is **out of scope**.

### Configuration needs

Each instance of the previously mentioned webapp has its own database (need for a specific connection string generated by management software). Also, we require a few beans to be customized in their string properties.

### The question

With focus to the self-managed and auto-manageable Tomcat server, we need to design an automated setup mechanisms (to be integrated in the failover we discussed before). Our problem right now is to **set the DB connection string** and **a few Spring beans' string properties** (these are shared 1-to-1 passcodes).

First, I came with my imagination to a possible solution, but I don't know if it's the "best" in terms of easiness and manageability.

The question is then:

- From a high level point of view, do you see major flaws in the approach described below?
- Do you know smarter solutions (perhaps with the ease of additional software) to achieve what I need to do?

### The approach

Since we have full source code, a Bash script may suffice:

1. Download a fresh copy from SVN production branch
2. Literally replace the connection string in `hibernate.cfg.xml` with the desired one (perhaps the file in the SVN branch contains a placeholder for string replacement)
3. Literally replace placeholders in Spring configuration file
4. Copy to Tomcat webapp folder under a new name
5. Wait for Tomcat to autodeploy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring supports placeholder.

The easiest way is to put a property file in the class path (if there is only one war running per server, in Tomcat lib dir, or if there is several war in the war/WEB-INF/class folder).

Most of the time the placeholder is used to define the DB connection (probably solving your hibernate config needs).

As there is several different way to retrieve the configuration you should use the big G to search for method for your case.